# canvas draw not smooth circles

Tags: android, canvas

At the first of my game, I draw some circles from alpha 0 to 255 using canvas(it's like making a fade_in animation by myself)

But if you see in picture(this picture captured in alpha 230),from alpha 0 to 254 these circles aren't smooth!(click on picture to see what I mean)

(and only when alpha become 255 the circles become smooth)
[image]
What's the problem and how can I fix this?

my code:
I have a game loop, that get canvas

`canvas = gameView.getHolder().lockCanvas();`

then in my view ,at first I set :

```
    paintAlpha = 0;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setAlpha(paintAlpha);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

then in every loop(every ticks) I do this:

```
    if(paintAlpha < 255) {
        paintAlpha+=1;
        paint.setAlpha(paintAlpha);
    }
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, currentRadius, paint);
```

Solution:
Thanks to @nitesh.
The problem was because of surfaceView that can't set anti alias to canvas (in View you don't have this problem ,I don't know why)
By using Bitmap and draw on it and finally draw bitmap by canvas , the problem solved (instead of drawing on canvas directly)

Comment: loop? what loop do you mean?

Comment: I said that it's a game ,I mean game thread loop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the following property to paint object

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

For better understanding and other approaches refer this link 
https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-why-your-canvas-shapes-arent-smooth-aa2a3f450eb5#.p9iktozdi

**From the article**

Draw a bitmap first if:
- You need to persist the image.
- You need to draw transparent pixels.
- Your shapes don’t change often and/or require time consuming operations.
Use anti-aliasing to draw smooth edges.
Avoid redraws on the bitmap if possible or else, clear a bitmap before redrawing.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 
                                     200, 
                                     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }
    bitmapCanvas.drawColor(
              Color.TRANSPARENT, 
              PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); //this line moved outside if
    drawOnCanvas(bitmapCanvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mLeftX, mTopY, p);
}

protected void drawOnCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(mLeftX + 100, mTopY + 100, 100, p);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I also set it,it doesn't help

Comment: see my updated answer and follow the approach in the article

Comment: you mean that when I want to draw something that it's alpha is less than 255 ,I need first draw a bitmap under it?

Comment: Thank you very much man,you solve my problem :) the problem was because of surfaceView and solved by bitmap trick.

Answer (score 2):

you can approach this by

```
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

or

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Comment: I also set it,it doesn't help